# stopping python requests during connection

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-requests, timeout

I'm working on a multithreading project where I open more connections with python requests in more threads.

These threads work in a loop. Over and under the loop there is an handler which tells the threads when to stop, but I can't stop threads until connection is over or timed out.

```py
# inside thread

while 1:
    if stop_:
        thread_event.set()

    r = requests.get('https://www.google.com', timeout=15)  # I need to manage the connection timeout

    if stop_:
        thread_event.set()
```

Comment: seems that you asking how to kill the running thread !

Comment: yes @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη